# Xcode Subversion Problem

Tags: svn, xcode

I am trying to get subversion up and running through xcode.

I'm following [Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/server/subversionwithxcode3.html).

Everything looks to be going okay until I try and add the repository, which indicates that the connection is established, but I am getting this error.

> The authenticity of host ' (::1)'
>   can't be established. RSA key
>   fingerprint is
>   6c:2e:0f:ee:4c:88:69:fb:5d:ff:0f:72:d3:af:83:ba

Under Subversion setting, I am putting in the following address in the URL: field.

```
svn+ssh:///Library/Subversion/Repository/Project1
```

If I select Add key, then it authenticates, but then this window pops up every time the program tries to access  subversion rendering it useless.

Have you ever seen anything like this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The *"The authenticity of host..."* message is actually not an error. It's a message which SSH generates on connection to a new host (when key/host is not yet known for the local host). You should check whether record with host/key is added successfully to **$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts**. Check [this](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-host-key-protection).